# Image inside HTML div block won't resize

Tags: html, css

Please look at the "About" tab of this website, and lines 51 to 55 of the source code.
https://lwymarie.github.io/

I intend that the three images float to the right of the text, all occupying 30% of the window's width. It seems that html code for resizing these images does not work, and the images are as big as their original sizes. I'm not sure what's wrong, since my html and css codes are rather simple.

For reference I'm copying the relevant source code.

```
    <div style="width:10%;float:right;margin:1em;">
        <img src="profile0.bmp" style="margin-bottom:1em;">
        <img src="Palomar.jpg" style="margin-bottom:1em;">
        <img src="Shane.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: Just add `width: 100%` to each `style` element in `img` tag.

Comment: use !Important, if you have any priority cdn

Comment: #About > div > img {
    width: 100%;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something like that in your CSS:

```
img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Otherwise, your images will overflow their container.

Or you can use inline CSS, as you have been doing:

```
<img src="profile0.bmp" style="margin-bottom:1em;width: 100%;">
```